# Electron-Prisma Error: can not find module '.prisma/client'

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron, nuxt.js, prisma

I'm building a Nuxt-electron-prisma app and I kinda stuck here. when I use prisma normally as guided every thing is fine on dev but on build i get this error :

```
A javascript error occurred in the main process
Uncaught exception:
Error: can not find module : '.prisma/client'
```

I tried changing prisma provider output to `../resources/prisma/client`

```js
generator client {
  provider = "prisma-client-js"
  output   = "../resources/prisma/client"
}
```

and in main.js of electron

```js
const { PrismaClient } = require('../resources/prisma/client');
const prisma = new PrismaClient()
```

but I get error `Cannot find module '_http_common' at webpackMissingModules` in both dev and build ! which by others opinion is caused when using prisma on client-side but I only use it on `background.js` (`main.js` of the my boilerplate)

I'm using [Nuxtron](https://github.com/saltyshiomix/nuxtron) boilerplate for Nuxt-electron which is using yml file for electron-builder config file and in it I also added prisma to files property:

```yaml
appId: com.example.app
productName: nuxt-electron-prisma
copyright: Copyright © 2021
nsis: 
  oneClick: false
  perMachine: true
  allowToChangeInstallationDirectory: true

directories:
  output: dist
  buildResources: resources
files:
  - "resources/prisma/database.db"
  - "node_modules/.prisma/**"
  - "node_modules/@prisma/client/**"
  - from: .
    filter:
      - package.json
      - app
publish: null
```

and still get errors

in my `win-unpacked/resources` I have this only: `win-unpacked\resources\app.asar.unpacked\node_modules\@prisma\engines`

[image]

and of course my package.json

```json
{
  "private": true,
  "name": "nuxt-electron-prisma",
  "productName": "nuxt-electron-prisma",
  "description": "",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "author": "",
  "main": "app/background.js",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "nuxtron",
    "build": "nuxtron build"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "electron-serve": "^1.0.0",
    "electron-store": "^6.0.1",
    "@prisma/client": "^3.0.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@mdi/font": "^6.1.95",
    "@nuxtjs/axios": "^5.13.6",
    "@nuxtjs/device": "^2.1.0",
    "@nuxtjs/dotenv": "^1.4.1",
    "@nuxtjs/vuetify": "1.12.1",
    "core-js": "^3.15.1",
    "electron": "^10.1.5",
    "electron-builder": "^22.9.1",
    "glob": "^7.1.7",
    "noty": "^3.2.0-beta",
    "nuxt": "^2.15.7",
    "nuxtron": "^0.3.1",
    "sass": "1.32.13",
    "swiper": "^5.4.5",
    "prisma": "^3.0.2",
    "vue-awesome-swiper": "^4.1.1"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69332497/3047439) provided by [Mojtaba Barari](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13318436/mojtaba-barari) works but it results in `@prisma` packages being present in both `resources/app/node_modules` and `resources/node_modules`.

There is a better way how to do it:

```json
{
  "build": {
    "extraResources": [
      {
        "from": "node_modules/.prisma/client/",
        "to": "app/node_modules/.prisma/client/"
      }
    ],
  }
}
```

In this case, the Prisma client files will be copied directly to `resources/app/node_modules` where other `@prisma` packages are already present and so you will save ~ 10 MB compared to the other solution.

**EDIT:**

My previous solution doesn't work if an application is packaged into an asar archive. You need to use `files` field instead:

```json
{
  "build": {
    "files": [
      {
        "from": "node_modules/.prisma/client/",
        "to": "node_modules/.prisma/client/"
      }
    ],
  }
}
```

This is a universal solution which works even if you don't use an asar archive.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I finally solved it!!
first of all no need to change client generator output direction!

```
//schema.prisma
datasource db {
  provider = "sqlite"
  url      = "file:../resources/database.db"
}
generator client {
  provider = "prisma-client-js"
  // output   = "../resources/prisma/client"  !! no need for this!
}
```

then in electron-builder config add `./prisma` , `@prisma` and database

```js
// my config file was a .yml
extraResources:
  - "resources/database.db"
  - "node_modules/.prisma/**/*"
  - "node_modules/@prisma/client/**/*"

// or in js
extraResources:[
  "resources/database.db"
  "node_modules/.prisma/**/*"
  "node_modules/@prisma/client/**/*"
]
```

this solved `Error: cannot find module : '.prisma/client'

but this alone won't read DB in built exe file!

so in main.js where importing `@prisma/client` should change DB reading directory:

```js
import { join } from 'path';
const isProd = process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production';

import { PrismaClient } from '@prisma/client';
const prisma = new PrismaClient({
  datasources: {
    db: {
      url: `file:${isProd ? join(process.resourcesPath, 'resources/database.db') : join(__dirname, '../resources/database.db')}`,
    },
  },
})
```

with these configs I could fetch data from my sqlite DB